# Error connecting web3js to react native application

Tags: react-native, blockchain, web3js

I ran into a problem connecting web3 to a React Native app.

Initially, the connection was made according to this [guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/tutorial-how-to-set-up-web3js-1-x-with-react-native-0-6x-2021-467b2e0c94a4).
Everything worked, but as soon as I restart the application, an error appears:

> ReferenceError: Property 'Buffer' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes
>
> ERROR Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered
> callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the
> error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine:
> hermes

Then I comment on these lines in Live reloading mode

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3Rospen = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/myKey')
```

I save the code, the application works, again, in Live reloading mode, I uncomment these lines back - the application works.

But initially, just taking and running the application from web3 does not work. Maybe someone faced such a problem?

Versions:

```
"react-native": "0.66.4",
"web3": "^1.7.3"
```

Comment: Any luck with this one? I'm facing the same issue currently...